# index error when inputing empty string in Python

Tags: python, string, indexing

So I am making a basic pig latin translator

```
word = raw_input("type a word, any word")
first = word[0]
rest = word[1:len(word)]
ay = "ay"

if word.isalpha() and len(word) > 0:
    print (rest + first + ay)
elif len(word) == 0:
    print "invalid entry"
else:
    print "invalid entry"
```

If I input an empty string the compiler returns:

> IndexError: string index out of range

How do I make it so that when I input an empty string the code will return "invalid entry"?

Answer (score 4):

Just move your logic inside the first if check

```
word = raw_input("type a word, any word")

if word.isalpha() and len(word) > 0:
    first = word[0]
    rest = word[1:len(word)]
    ay = "ay"
    print (rest + first + ay)
elif len(word) == 0:
    print "invalid entry"
else:
    print "invalid entry"
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need to check `if word` as empty strings evaluate to `False` and use a single else statement, your second elif is unnecessary as the word will either have a least one char and be alpha or not:

```
word = raw_input("type a word, any word")

if word.isalpha() and word: 
    first = word[0] # will only try to index if word is not an empty string or not alpha
    rest = word[1:len(word)]
    ay = "ay"
    print (rest + first + ay)
else:
    print "invalid entry"

In [11]: bool("") 
Out[11]: False

In [12]: bool("foo")
Out[12]: True
```

You can also use [ternary conditional operator](http://www.pythoncentral.io/one-line-if-statement-in-python-ternary-conditional-operator/)

```
word = raw_input("type a word, any word")

print word[1:] + word[0] + "ay" if word.isalpha() and word else "invalid entry"
```

Answer (score 0):

as your error surely would point you to the second line

```
first = word[0]
```

you are calling the first character in the string because the index starts at 0
so you are asking for and index that does not exist... 
further more if you asked for -1 (the next to last character in the list ) you will reach an index error as well.
so you should only ask for index values when you are aware of the index range so stated in another answer love the block of code lines 2-3 inside of the if statement checking for index values this leaves the code still dynamically stable by insuring the value of "ay" is set no matter what in case you wish to use it latter on as part of of an error message; i also removed the repetitive elif statement assuming you don't care to know if it failed because it had numbers or because of its len.
**side note to keep in mind that isalpha will return a false if the string has a hyphen "-" or like wise in it!**

```
word = raw_input("type a word, any word")
ay = "ay"
if word.isalpha() and len(word) > 0:
    first = word[0]
    rest = word[1:len(word)]
    print (rest + first + ay)
else:
    print "invalid entry"
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Replace `word[1:len(word)]` with `word[1:]`.
2. This wont fix your out of bound Problem. Think of a word with length equals one.
3. Check first if word is not None and not “".
4. Check if word length is bigger zero.
5. Check if word length is bigger one and set rest.